# How to generate vector pattern of random dots with specific density?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, patterns, fill

## I want to make a field of dots.

#### Primary

- Dots should be randomly placed
- I want to specify the density of dots (e.g. 10 dots per inch, 40 dots per inch, or 20%, 60%)

#### Secondary

- Dots should not touch
- I can replace dot with other shapes.

Essentially I am looking for an equivalent of the scatter brush for fill.

#### Best approach so far

- Make a grid of dots in Illustrator, using <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> to accelerate the grid-building.
- Select all and use *Transform Each*: set the horizontal and vertical movement to half the gap between dots (so that the dots can never overlap, and tick *Random* on.

This generates a somewhat random field of dots (or any other object) but isn't entirely successful:

- The result is still very grid-like. The dots (pips?) aren't perfectly aligned, but they are still in loose rows and columns. (If I loosen my requirement that dots don't touch, I can set a movement radius larger than the gaps and these columns disappear.)
- Also, while the math is pretty simple to determine the density of dots, ideally I would only have to enter my desired density and the computer would do that math. This would allow for more experimentation.

I have also tried the *Symbol Sprayer* but this is even less precise.

*I am hoping to do this in Illustrator; SVG or any other free vector approach would also work.*

Comment: Here's a commercial plugin (no affiliation) that looks like it might do this for you (and much more) - in fact it looks really cool. https://astutegraphics.com/software/colliderscribe/

Comment: @mayersdesign Yup that looks pretty cool. When I have the $32 ...

Comment: @Unrelated You can use the full functionality for 14 days as a free trial... I can help you with a random fill but you'd still have to figure out the density percentages yourself.

Comment: Also: are you trying to fill just a simple rectangle or some other shape?

Answer (score 5):

What exactly is the problem with the symbol sprayer?  From your description it would seem to do what you want. Here I moved the brush in little circular motions to increase the randomness.

[image]

Here are the settings I used for the symbol sprayer

[image]

Comment: Thanks. One of the problems (either with the tool or, more likely, with my understanding) is the lack of precision. Densities one integer apart change the density a lot, and it seems decimals aren't allowed. Also, it seems you're stuck with the circular blob, unless you want to *draw* with the sprayer which 1) leaves gaps and shows the path you drew and 2) still leaves a blobby shape (is there any way to crop these or do I need to use a mask?)

Comment: @Unrelated Well, yes you're right. It's integers only. However you could get a bit more fine control if you were to make a bounding box, with fill and stroke set to none, around the dot, then make that into a symbol.  See example [here](http://imgur.com/CRKxLiS). To crop you could use a clipping mask, or you could expand and ungroup the symbol set and simply delete the dots you don't need.

Comment: Ah the bounding box makes sense

Answer (score 3):

Another quick and dirty option would be to use [Jongware's CircleFill script](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/732621).

[image: Something Like this]

It's super useful and pretty versatile for filling a specific area. It displays a simple dialog, where you can set a maximum and minimum circle size as a percentage of the selected object size. In addition, you can select either a plain basic color, or select any of your current Swatch Groups; in that case, each of the circles are filled with a random color from that group. You can also specify the spacing between each circle.