# How can I reproduce those stroke and fill a shape with it?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, fill

[image]

Hello there,

Is there a way to fill a particular shape with stroke/lines in a randomized angle and position. Which would allow me to avoid doing it by hand ... lazy me!
I put a picture so you can have an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks in advance!
Cheers

Comment: Possibly https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/95512 answers this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate vector pattern of random dots with specific density?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/95512/how-to-generate-vector-pattern-of-random-dots-with-specific-density)

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use programmed add-ons and you'll get a collection of different dots if you use Inkscape. There's the sprayer. You select a few different drawn dots and spray them. You can put "no overlaps" ON. You can group the drawn dots with guard circles to keep minimum distances.

In the next image 7 different dots were drawn and grouped with red circles. The circles with dots were selected and sprayed few seconds:

[image]

The result was ungrouped, one circle was selected, Edit > Select same > Fill color was applied and DEL was pressed. The resulted fill:

[image]

Denser result can be got by having smaller circles. With no circles the result is this:

[image]

It would increase the density as long as some free room is found under the nozzle. If overlaps were allowed the result would finally become full black.

To fill an area use the area as clipping mask or combine all dots in a cloud to a compound path and make an intersection.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the symbol sprayer as a starting base, as mentioned by Billy in **[his answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/95514/63979)**.

Now, expand the paths using **Object → Expand** and *Ungroup* everything (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>).

To get some more variation on each line/circle/dash, you will need to use scripts, such as **[Organify](https://github.com/johnwun/js4ai/blob/master/Organify.js)** and **[Random Resize](http://vectorboom.com/load/freebies/freescripts/randomresizeopacity/22-1-0-152)** (both set to low numbers for minor differences) to get some natural looking effects.

---

Some other scripts which may be helpful in this project:

[Arc Twister](https://github.com/johnwun/js4ai/blob/master/ArcTwister.jsx)
[Random Move](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/111271/63979) (by *joojaa* in an answer on this site)
[Random Rotate](http://dotpixeldesign.com/random-rotate-illustrator-script/)
[Random Select](https://www.scriptopedia.org/en/component/phocadownload/file/20-randomselect.html) (if you want to apply scripts/changes to only a random selection of the paths)

> Also, be sure to check out [illustrator-scripting](/questions/tagged/illustrator-scripting) tag, I'm sure you will find helpful resources there as well.